# conversion from Eigen::AngleAxisd to Eigen::Vector3d

Tags: c++, geometry, eigen, eigen3

I have a conversion from a rotation vector to a rotation matrix by:

```
Eigen::Vector3d rotVec(-0.67925191, -1.35850382, -2.03775573);
Eigen::AngleAxisd rotAA(rotVec.norm(), rotVec.normalized());
Eigen::Matrix3d rotationMatrix = rotAA.matrix();
```

Then I want to do the reverse conversion from matrix to the vector and what I do is:

```
Eigen::AngleAxisd rotvec2(rotationMatrix);
```

yet, I have not been able to convert Eigen::AngleAxisd back to Eigen::Vector3d and the AngleAxisd itself seems to only have an angle and axis member function.

Does anyone know how we can do this?

Answer (score 1):

`AngleAxis` has many more member functions than `angle()` and `axis()`. Either `fromRotationMatrix(const MatrixBase< Derived > &mat)` or `AngleAxis(const MatrixBase< Derived > &mat)` will do the first step in converting back. See: https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1AngleAxis.html

Then use the product `angle() * axis()` to get back the original vector.

```cpp
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <cstdlib>

int main()
{
    using namespace Eigen;
    using T = double;

    Vector3<T> const rotVec{-0.67925191, -1.35850382, -2.03775573};
    AngleAxis<T> const rotAA{rotVec.norm(), rotVec.normalized()};
    Matrix3<T> const rotMat{rotAA.toRotationMatrix()};

#if 0
    AngleAxis<T> rotAA2{};
    rotAA2.fromRotationMatrix(rotMat);
#else
    AngleAxis<T> const rotAA2{rotMat};
#endif

    Vector3<T> const rotVec2{rotAA2.angle() * rotAA2.axis()};
    bool const is_valid = rotVec.isApprox(rotVec2);
    return is_valid ? EXIT_SUCCESS : EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```